# Kali 1.0 - can't use apt-get or install notepadqq

Tags: bash, kali-linux, repository, apt-mirror

I can't get anything to install via `apt-get` and I'm using Kali 1.0. I also can't get notepadqq to install. How can I get this to work?

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get update

Err http://­security.kali.org sana/updates Release.gpg      

  Could not resolve '­security.kali.org'

Err http://­http.kali.org sana Release.gpg    

  Could not resolve '­http.kali.org'

Reading package lists... Done     

W: Failed to fetch http://­http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '­http.kali.org'


W: Failed to fetch http://­security.kali.org/­kali-security/dists/sana/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve '­security.kali.org'


W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get notepadqq

E: Invalid operation notepadqq

root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get install notepadqq

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package notepadqq

root@kali:~/Desktop# cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://­http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib

deb-src http://­http.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib


deb http://­security.kali.org/­kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://­security.kali.org/­kali-security/ sana/updates main contrib non-freeroot@kali:~/Desktop#
```

Comment: a) did you `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` before you attempted to do this?

b) can you post the content of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Question edited. Please check

Comment: OK, that's too much, you should put content like that in a http://pastebin.com/ page.  In any case, it's `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` that we need.

Comment: Post readited. Please check once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your repositories to:

`deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main contrib non-free 
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free`

Then next, I'd recommend just using gedit, which is in the repositories; otherwise, you should build notepadqq from source::

`$ git clone https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq.git
$ cd notepadqq
notepadqq$ ./configure --prefix /usr
notepadqq$ make
notepadqq$ sudo make install`

per: https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq

Comment: <pre> root@kali:~# git clone https://github.com/­notepadqq/­notepadqq.git Cloning into '­notepadqq'... error: The requested URL returned error: 400 while accessing https://github.com/­notepadqq/­notepadqq.git/info/refs fatal: HTTP request failed root@kali:~# cd notepadqq bash: cd: notepadqq: No such file or directory root@kali:~# </pre>

Comment: @Joe_Vj_95: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux