# kali linux 2019.1. And can't install any thing

Tags: kali-linux, gnome-terminator

I just freshly installed Kali linux 2019.1 and i couldn't install anyting on it.

For example: I want to install termiantor but it fail.

```
root@kali:~# apt install terminator 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package terminator**
```

And i also try `apt-get install terminator` it fails.

I updated and install the `apt` and `apt-get`. No Results

I also updated the kali repositories. by `/etc/apt/sources.list`; No Results

And I also clearing the contents (these are dependencies in that file) of `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and then use `apt update && apt install -f`; No Results

Please help. Any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: Please add contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Please run `apt update` and add output. Please explain "_it fails_" from your question. Is `terminator` a supported application in Kali?

Comment: You can't install anything or just `terminator`? What other packages have you tried installing and failed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kali 1.0 - can't use apt-get or install notepadqq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251284/kali-1-0-cant-use-apt-get-or-install-notepadqq)

Answer (score 0):

`terminator` is packaged in kali-linux rolling-release, it can be installed after editing your `sources.list`:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" | \
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install terminator
```

[kali packages : terminator](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/terminator)